# Trust Relationship between containers in Java EE 6

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, glassfish, java-ee-6

in [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbyr/index.html) there's lack of information on making 2 containers trust each other, quote from "Trust between Containers":

> When an enterprise bean is designed so that either the original caller identity or a designated identity is used to call a target bean, the target bean will receive the propagated identity only. The target bean will not receive any authentication data.
>
> There is no way for the target container to authenticate the propagated security identity. However, because the security identity is used in authorization checks (for example, method permissions or with the isCallerInRole method), it is vitally important that the >security identity be authentic. Because no authentication data is available to >authenticate the propagated identity, the target must trust that the calling container has >propagated an authenticated security identity.
>
> **By default, the GlassFish Server is configured to trust identities that are propagated from different containers. Therefore, you do not need to take any special steps to set up a trust relationship.**

The last part scares me. But anyway, I would like to know how to make 2 containers trust AND not trust each other, and if this is possible between Tomcat 5.5 and Glassfish 3.1.2 (because I need to use the @RunAs from 1 container to the other another).

To further clarify my problem, I will tell you what I have to do and my solution:

I'm making a Restful webservice to allow a client download a file, this webservice is located at *CONTAINER_A*, but before downloading the file, the webservices makes a call on an EJB in *CONTAINER_B* to get the path of the file from a Database, also in *CONTAINER_B*. The thing is, I want to make sure that calls on the EJB from *CONTAINER_B* are only accesed by the webservice in CONTAINER_A, and I'm using the @RunAs annotation in the webservice so it acts as an *AUTHORIZED_ROLE*. The thing is, the client that access the webservice, let's call it the *WEB_CLIENT*, doesn't have to be authenticated to access the webservice, but the EJB in *CONTAINER_B* is secured to only be accesed by *AUTHORIZED_ROLE*.

Is it clear? Or am I over complicating things? Is there a better approach? Because the @RunAs solution is only usable when I make the JAX-RS webservice a @Stateless bean also, and it's discouraged to use file system operations (like reading the file and sending it back), but for now is the only solution I can think of.